# VBA if else loop in excel returning #VALUE

Tags: vba, excel

Hi All in new to using VBA in excel and was trying to create a function that would look at a number and return it as a six digit number.

The function I wrote to try and accomplish this is below but when I use the command =Res(A1) in a cell I just get a #VALUE! as the answer.

The value in cell one at the moment is 30508.

Any help anyone could offer to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks Guys.

```
Function Res(myval As Integer) As Integer

Res = 0

If ((myval > 0) And (myval < 10)) Then    
    Res = myval * 100000

ElseIf ((myval > 9) And (myval < 100)) Then
    Res = myval * 10000

ElseIf ((myval > 99) And (myval < 1000)) Then 
    Res = myval * 1000

ElseIf ((myval > 999) And (myval < 10000)) Then  
    Res = myval * 100

ElseIf ((myval > 9999) And (myval < 100000)) Then
    Res = myval * 10

ElseIf ((myval > 999999) And (myval < 10000000)) Then
    Res = myval / 10

Else
    Res = myval

End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change `Function Res(myval As Integer) As Integer` to:

```
Function Res(myval As Long) As Long
```

You're hitting the integer maximum.

Long stands for long integer, and you want to use it anytime your number could go above 30k.

Comment: Right. An integer's maximum is + or - 32767

Comment: Yeah. I use 30k as a mental stopping point because I always forget the exact #. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: That's sorted that, thank you very much for the reply's. That was actually one of the things I thought it would be but when I searched the range for an int I was looking at the wrong int in the table. I used that link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx but looked at the first int range which was 2,147,483,647 but I'm guessing I'm using a short int. Thanks again sheet is complete now and works great :D.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use long instead of integer

integer only covers from -32,768 to 32,767

long covers -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

```
    Function Res(myval As Long) As Long

    Res = 0

    If ((myval > 0) And (myval < 10)) Then    
       Res = myval * 100000

    ElseIf ((myval > 9) And (myval < 100)) Then
        Res = myval * 10000

    ElseIf ((myval > 99) And (myval < 1000)) Then 
        Res = myval * 1000

    ElseIf ((myval > 999) And (myval < 10000)) Then  
        Res = myval * 100

    ElseIf ((myval > 9999) And (myval < 100000)) Then
        Res = myval * 10

    ElseIf ((myval > 999999) And (myval < 10000000)) Then
        Res = myval / 10

    Else
        Res = myval

    End If

    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Function Res(myVal as long) As Long
    Res = myVal * 10 ^ ( 6 - Len(Cstr(myVal)) )
End Function
```

Note - this still suffers from the same problem as the original approach:

If myVal is 9999999 (7 digits) then myVal/10 is 999999.9 and Clng(999999.9) is 10000000 (still seven digits)